# How can I use a string as a month name parameter

Tags: java, date, calendar, java.util.date

I have an excel file with dates in this format `31/08/13`. What I need to do is to calculate a monthly interest based on the dates. The problem is that I need to know the number of days of the month.

Here is how I'm getting the month name inside of a loop:

```
getMonth = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[currentMonth-1]; //february
```

where `getMonth` is a string and `currentMonth` is the month number.

Now I'm trying to get the number of days with:

```
Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(1999, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);
int daysInMonth = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 28
```

My problem is that I can not(and its logic) replace `FEBRUARY` with the `getMonth` string, which is containing the month's name.

I know there is a much easier way to achieve it, but I'm really not able to spot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `Calendar.FEBRUARY` and other constants in `Calendar` class is `int`. You should change `getMonth` to an `int`, to make the constructor compile. Or, directly use `currentMonth - 1` in the constructor parameter, and by pass the creation of `getMonth` variable.

**P.S:** `getMonth` is really not a good name for a variable denoting a month. It's not a getter is it?

Comment: how can I cast the string `february` to int?

Comment: @Slim Don't create `getMonth` at all. Just use `currentMonth - 1`.

Comment: I can't replace `FEBRUARY` with any integer. It says: `Calendar cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: @Slim You have to replace `Calendar.FEBRUARY` with `currentMonth - 1`, in the constructor.

Comment: Got it! HUGE thanks for the help! I knew that I'm missing something small! Thanks again!